# Outputting to log file fails, but PS6 script runs with no errors

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I have other software that is exporting csv files, and when everything runs correctly I have 1291 lines in the csv. I am trying to easily identify which files are incomplete.

### This is my very first venture into PowerShell. I modified this code that I found on stackoverflow:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem 'd:\*.txt'

ForEach ($file in $files) {
    $lineCount = Get-Content -LiteralPath $file | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count
    Write-Output "File $($file.Name) has $lineCount lines"
    if ($lineCount -gt 50) {
        Write-Warning "Warning $($file.Name) is too big"
    }
}
```

---

### and managed to get this far without having errors:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem 'D:\!__DATA for searches\__CSVs\*.csv'

$logfile = 'D:\!__DATA for searches\__CSVs\CompletedFiles.txt'

ForEach ($file in $files) {
    $lineCount = Get-Content -LiteralPath $file | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count
    Write-Output "File $($file.Name) has $lineCount lines"
    if ($lineCount -gt 1290) {
        Write-Warning "Warning $($file.Name) is completed"   | Out-File $logfile -Append
    } 
}
```

---

### and also this variation

```
$files = Get-ChildItem 'D:\!__DATA for searches\__CSVs\*.csv'

ForEach ($file in $files) {
    $lineCount = Get-Content -LiteralPath $file | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count
    Write-Output "File $($file.Name) has $lineCount lines"
    if ($lineCount -gt 1290) {
        Write-Warning "Warning $($file.Name) is completed"  | Out-File 'D:\!__DATA for searches\__CSVs\CompletedFiles.txt' -append
   } 
}
```

---

but neither write to the log file. The script runs fine in the PS6 console, identifying the files with 1291 lines.

So I need the log file, plus I would like to also move the completed files to another directory in the same script, so input on what/where to make that happen is also greatly appreciated.

Thanks to the answer and other research I finished the script

```
$files = Get-ChildItem 'D:\!__DATA for searches\__CSVs\*.csv'
$logfile = 'D:\!__DATA for searches\__CSVs\CompletedFiles.txt'

ForEach ($file in $files) {
    $lineCount = Get-Content -LiteralPath $file | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count
#    Write-Output "File $($file.Name) has $lineCount lines"
    if ($lineCount -gt 1290) {
#        Write-Warning "Warning $($file.Name) is completed" 3>&1 |Out-File $logfile -Append
    Write-Output  "File $($file.Name) has $lineCount lines, and moving to D:\Completed\" 3>&1 | Out-File $logfile -Append
     Move-Item "D:\!__DATA for searches\__CSVs\$($file.Name)" "D:\!__DATA for searches\Completed\" -Force
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Write-Warning` doesn't send anything to `stdout`.

You can redirect the Warning stream with syntax somewhat similar to that of `cmd`:

```
Write-Warning "Warning $($file.Name) is completed" 3>> $logfile
```

or

```
Write-Warning "Warning $($file.Name) is completed" 3>&1 |Out-File $logfile -Append
```

Comment: how about its behavior in pwsh as mentioned by @user3345612

Comment: @Mathias  R. Jessen  I used your second option, and thankyou for the answer I needed

Comment: @PRASOON KARUNAN V   not sure of your comment, but using the code currently the script opens a console window but runs silently and window closes without anything written to it